# struct in union initialize

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, unions

Currently, I have a struct in a union. For example,

```
Struct foo{
    Union u{
         Struct s1{
             int i1;
         } ss1;
         Struct s2{
             int i2;
         } ss2;
    } wrap;
};
```

So when I want to initialize the union, I tried to do like this.

```
foo f = {};
f.u.ss1 = {
    .i1 = 0;
}
```

But the error shows no match for operator = (operand types and braced-enclosed initializer list).

So what is the right way to do the initialize? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `f.wrap.ss1.i1 = 0`? Once you fix the *other* errors to make it build (like the upper-case letters for `struct` and `union`).

Comment: Post real code - things like `Struct` are not C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry I made a typo, it should be ss1. However, in my real code, there are multiple variables in the struct s1, so simply use assignment does not work.

Comment: `f.wrap.ss1 = {0};` Add members and corresponding initializers to taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialisation should be:

```
foo f;
f.wrap.ss1 = {0 /*, comma seperated values, */};
```