# union inside a struct -- how to do designated initializer?

Tags: c++, struct

I have already read [struct in union initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689166/struct-in-union-initialize) and it does not address my issue

In my legacy code, I have tons of struct-with-union like

```
typedef struct st 
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8    sign ;
            uint8    cells;    
        }s;
        int    data;
    }u;
    int   extra;
} st;
```

Under C, below compiles:

```
static const st someval = {
    .sign = 0, .cells ={ 0 },  
    .cells = { 11 }
};
```

Is there a way to minimally change the compilation method (or code) to make it compiler under g++?

Comment: What version of C++ can/are you going to use?

Comment: c++ has no named parameters (i guess thats what the code is using)

Comment: @user463035818 C++20 does ;)

Comment: @user463035818 [but they are comming](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)

Comment: Your code compiles with `-std=gnuc++11`

Comment: @NathanOliver omg how cool is this. I am missing this feature since I wrote my last piece of FORTRAN many years ago

Comment: @user463035818 I've never had it so I'm not sure if I'll use it.  The C++ version is more limiting then the C version but it does look interesting.  At least with this all you need to remember is the names of the members, and not their order to brace initialize.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well actually you have to remember the order *also*, because C++'s version fails to compile if you initialize them out of order.

Comment: @NicolBolas Dang.  I missed that.  Not sure if I'll ever use it then.

Comment: @NathanOliver they're pretty nice for cases where you have many members that you want to zero initialize, but few that need specific initialization. Especially when the initialized object is const like it is here.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> static const st someval = {
>      .sign = 0, .cells ={ 0 },  
> //              ^
>      .cells = { 11 } };
> //   ^
> ```

You initialize `cells` twice, which makes this ill-formed in C++.

Also, neither `sign` nor `cell` are direct members of `st`. The declaration [is ill formed in C as well](https://godbolt.org/z/NH9Vpl).

Following would be correct use of designated initializers in C++20 (a future C++ standard which is proposed to introduce designated initializers to the language):

```
static const st someval = {
     .u{.s{.sign = 0, .cells = 11}},
     // NOTE .extra left zero-initialized
};
```

or following, which is correct in both C++20 and C:

```
static const st someval = {
     .u = {.s = {.sign = 0, .cells = 11}},
};
```

The current C++ standard doesn't have designated initializers however. You can write a function that creates a local non-const zero-initialized `st` object, then use member accessors to initialize the specific members that you want to initialize, and then return the object. Then you can initialize the const `st` object with a call to that function. That initialization function might not be useful anywhere else, so you might want to use a lambda to avoid needlessly polluting the namespace.:

```
static const st someval = []() {
    st o {};
    o.u.s.sign = 0;
    o.u.s.cells = 11;
    return o;
}();
```

Comment: Note that C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶19](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19) says: _The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject;_ and has footnote 151 which says _Any initializer for the subobject which is overridden and so not used to initialize that subobject might not be evaluated at all._  So, the double-initialization of `.cells` is pointless but permitted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler indeed in C, but not in C++. I added clarifying qualification.